# Superset Error : werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not Found: The requested

Tags: python, apache-superset

I' using superset to create dashboards and it's working but I keep getting this error that make superset functioning weirdly

```
    2022-08-01 18:21:53,169:WARNING:superset.views.base:HTTPException
superset_app             | Traceback (most recent call last):
superset_app             |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
superset_app             |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
superset_app             |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1492, in dispatch_request
superset_app             |     self.raise_routing_exception(req)
superset_app             |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1474, in raise_routing_exception
superset_app             |     raise request.routing_exception  # type: ignore
superset_app             |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/ctx.py", line 376, in match_request
superset_app             |     result = self.url_adapter.match(return_rule=True)  # type: ignore
superset_app             |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 2042, in match
superset_app             |     raise NotFound()
superset_app             | werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```